# Install react-native-community/react-native-video on expo kit

Tags: react-native, video, expo

In expo kit projects react-native link doesnt work for react-native-community/react-native-video.  Android app stops running and IOS throws the error when the video component is used.

Answer (score 0):

Okay a finall worked this out of weeks of fiddling.

1. npm install --save react-native-video
2. react-native link react-native-video
3. cd ios
4. pod install
5. open xcode and run project - it should work now on IOS
6. open android studio
7. open android/settings.gradle
8. change the line:
9. List item

   project(':react-native-video').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer')

to

project(':react-native-video').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-video/android')